# Can't connect to postgres database

Tags: linux, networking, database, postgresql

Im trying to connect to a DB with Postgres JDBC, both machines are linux

1. the firewall, selinux, iptables are down on both machines
2. I can connect to the DB, (on my personal windows computer) with
   Mobaxterm and DBeaver using ssh: ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:5432
   root@dbhost
3. they can ping each other
4. I can Telnet to port 22, but no 5432
5. I get this when I run the command netstat -nlp | grep 5432 `tcp    0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      86870/postgres`

I have added this lines at the end of postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

I have added this lines pg_hba.conf

```
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5
host    all         all         ::/0                  md5
```

and I have run this query to reload the config
`SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

but still can't connect, What do you recommend?

Comment: Did you restart the service after adding those lines?

Comment: no, I read that you can reload the config with SELECT pg_reload_conf();....do you think that will not work?...Im afraid on restarting the service because it has NNM running getting data from multiple machines

Comment: It's not going to read the config file again until you restart the service.